# A template choice decision source code

Tags: theming, 8, hooks

I am trying to find the code that is responsible for deciding which template file to choose in different cases. For example I need find out what are possible template names for the form rendering.

I have tried to find this grepping source code for key words, but unfortunately, haven't found this part of code.

Please explain the flow and where I can find this logic in the Drupal Core.

P.S. I've already enabled debug mode, but not all suggestions are displayed.

Comment: Aside from Views, every template suggestion available to you is available in the theme debug source output.

Comment: If you need to change things, then you can implement [hook_theme_suggestions_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_alter/8.2.x)